# Mirrored displays with full-screen programs in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have 2 displays hooked up to my gaming desktop running Ubuntu 20.04. One is a monitor (connected to display port) and one is a TV (connected to HDMI). They are both the same resolution (3840 × 2160). I have the display settings set up so they are mirrored.

Both displays have multiple inputs and are used by different people. For example, someone might be using the monitor for work while I play video games on the TV, or might be watching TV while I play games on the monitor. I use the "mirrored" setup because this way it doesn't matter what display I want to use - I can always see what I want on the display I have access to at the time.

This generally works fine, *except* for when I play games (or use any application) in fullscreen mode. In this case I can only ever get the game to appear on one of the 2 displays. If this is not the display I want, then I have to literally pull the cable from the other display in order to "force" the game to show up on the display I am actually using. This is very annoying since the cables aren't very accessible and I often have to interrupt someone to do this. It's even more annoying to re-connect them.

When something is displaying fullscreen on one monitor, the other monitor seems to display everything else that the fullscreen application is "drawing over". When I exit fullscreen mode, the displays are properly mirrored again.

I *could* "just" use the display settings to route what I want to the "correct" display each time by just telling the computer to use only one display. But then I have to remember to set it back up to mirrored mode afterwards, so I don't lose the ability to reconfigure things on whichever display I happen to have access to.

I'm also very close to buying an HDMI switch, but I do also occasionally use both displays at once, and that would defeat that use case.

This also causes problems when trying to access the desktop remotely with certain programs. Everything will be fine until I launch something in fullscreen mode and then I can't see anything over the remote connection any longer.

I have tried so many combinations of xrandr, etc. to try to fix this, and read through so many forum posts, etc., but nothing seems to work. Hoping someone might have an idea here. Thank you so much for any help!

My video card is a Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1660 Ti OC 6G, and I'm using the nvidia driver.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the type of video card and which driver is being used? This might help someone answer the question more accurately.

Comment: Good call - updated!